# glScissor(0,0,0,0) hard-crashes Apple iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es-2.0

According to the OpenGL docs, it's legal:

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glScissor.xml

> "and glScissor(0,0,0,0) doesn't allow modification of any pixels in
>   the window."

...but when I do it on iOS 6, it triggers the dreaded "PowerVR SGX chip crashed":

> gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart ()

On iOS 5.x, I had no crash (UPDATED: I just discovered that when moving from 5 to 6 I also changed my animation counter to start at zero rather than one, so it's very possible I had the same crash on iOS 5) - but whether that's because this is an iOS 6 bug, or because iOS 6 changes the timing of the code, I can't tell. It could easily be that in iOS 5 I never submitted 0,0,0,0, but instead submitted 0,0,0,1 as my first call (the scissor is being animated frame to frame).

---

UPDATE: the height can be zero, the PowerVR only crashes if the width is 0.

x, y, (width==0)? 1 : width, height -- never crashes
x, y, width, (height==0 ? 1 : height -- crashes whenever width==0

NB: I've checked, asserted, and used logging to prove that width and height are never less than zero (that was my first thought!)

---

More info, possibly related (apparently causes a problem in previous Apple OpenGL drivers):

I'm using multiple FBOs, and for each frame I do:

1. glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer1.glName );

   1. (render to texture 1)
2. glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer2.glName );

   1. (render to texture 2)
3. glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer3.glName );

   1. (read from texture 2, render to texture 3)
4. [((GLKView*)self.view) bindDrawable];

   1. (render texture 1 to screen)
5. [((GLKView*)self.view) bindDrawable];

   1. glScissor( 0, 0, width, height )   // where width and height increase each frame
   2. (render texture 3 to screen)

Comment: This seems like a major bug. If you can, I would strongly advise testing it on the iOS 7 betas, and if it's still broken, file a radar with apple *immediately*.

Comment: I don't have a spare device I can afford to install iOS 7 on :(. For now, I'm using the workaround above (it prevents the crash), and I'll revisit when iOS 7 is out.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and it seems to work as expected for me.

```
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glScissor(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

... results in no rendering at all on iOS 6.1.4 on an iPhone 5. Using a non-zero size renders as expected, too.

The crash might be connected to some setup that differs from mine. I'm rendering from a `GLKView`. If you need more info, let me know. I could try on an iOS 7 device, for example.

Comment: Ah ... one thing that might be related. I found some reports on the web with glScissor being broken on some hardware if you're switching FBOs, and I'm swithcing between 4 FBOs (3 of mine, then finally a [GLKView bindDrawable] to bring back Apple's and do the final render)

Comment: @Adam Can you create a small example project showcasing the crash?

Comment: I tried, but Apple's Xcode template defeated me - it's taking way too long to convert their hand-written vertices etc into simple, working GLKit code. I don't have time to fix their template as well as diagnose a problem which I've already found a workaround (don't send 0 width). When I have time to write a working Xcode template from scratch, that uses GLKit properly, I'll try this again.